# Unable to Implement Foreign Key Constraint in One-to-Many Relationship in NestJS with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to establish a one-to-many relationship between two entities (Token and User) in my NestJS application using TypeORM. I have defined the entities as shown below:

For the Token entity:

```js
@Entity('tokens')
export default class Token {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  token: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.tokens)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user' })
  user: User;

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  @Generated('uuid')
  refreshToken: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

And the User entity:

```js
@Entity('users')
export default class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  mobileNumber: string;

  @Column({ length: 25, nullable: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ length: 25, nullable: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Column('json', { nullable: false })
  secret: any;

  @OneToMany(() => Token, (token) => token.user)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'tokens' })
  tokens: Token[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

However, when I try to run the code, I encounter the following error:

```
[Nest] 51035  - 07/17/2023, 8:11:20 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
QueryFailedError: foreign key constraint "FK_2b37c2056a01602dbc597d716e8" cannot be implemented
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue and any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm simply trying to have a one-to-many relationship between Tokens and Users.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you sure that this error comes from this relation. I have copied your models definitions and typeorm generated the two tables correctly. Check if there is another entity or relation giving this error. Also erase all the tables in DB an run again your app.

Comment: Remember, in onetomany side joincolumn is not required.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late, but I assume problem is `@JoinColumn()` decorator on "One" side of the relation. From Token side it is clear that `@JoinColumn("user")` will translate into a column called "user" which will hold ID of the user. This is everything DB needs to know about this relation, no column on User side is required. `user.tokens` is an ORM abstraction, it does not exist as a column.

To learn more about violated constraint you can either connect to DB and inspect table constraints, or - if you're using migrations - generate migration and see how it is declared.